# Why, in some situation does "git checkout origin/branch" result in "detached at <SHA>" instead of "detached at origin/master"?

Tags: git

I'm working on a large enough repo, with multiple submodules.  To ensure we're in a correct state during a CI process, we init the submodules,

```
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule sync
$ git submodule update --force
```

which prints out something like,

```
Synchronizing submodule url for 'android/public'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'ios/public'
...

Submodule path 'android/public': checked out 'asdf1234'
Submodule path 'ios/public': checked out 'bsdf2345'
```

If we then go through and check out a few different branches, if we then run

```
$ for platform in android ios
$ do
$   (cd $platform/public; git fetch --all; git checkout origin/master)
$ done
```

and check those folders with `git branch`, they all say `(HEAD detached at origin/master)`.

If however we redo the submodule initialisation at the top, and run

```
$ for platform in android ios
$ do
$   (cd $platform/public; git fetch --all; git reset --hard origin/master; git checkout origin/master)
$ done
```

And check these again with `git branch`, they show up as `(HEAD detached at <some SHA>)`.

This is kind of a legacy procedure in our CI, so it could be changed, but I'd still like to know why running `git checkout origin/master` wouldn't *always* result in `git branch` displaying the HEAD detached at `origin/master`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "detached at" string is merely an attempt to be informative.  Older versions of Git use *only* a hash ID and you will only ever see "detached at <hash>".

Newer versions of Git attempt to remember items from the `git checkout` command that did the detaching, and will say "detached at something_more_informative" if they can.  Here you will sometimes see `detached at origin/master`.  They will lose the detail in various cases, including if you move the current commit (by writing new commit IDs into `HEAD`, e.g., using by `git checkout` again or by making new commits).  In this case some newer versions of Git will begin to say "detached *from*" instead of "detached at", and hang on to some extra information, whether it's a hash ID or a name.  While all newer Git versions attempt to do this, some have some minor bugs and will fail to distinguish "detached from" and "detached at" properly.

In *this particular case*—although it's Git-version-dependent—chances are that the reason your last example process results in "detached at *hash*" is that your `git reset --hard origin/master` moves to the given commit by ID, clobbering the old retained information, and then your `git checkout origin/master` sees that this is not a *move*, i.e., you're already *at* that ID, so it does not update the retained hash-or-name.

If that's the case, simply replacing the `git reset --hard origin/master` with `git reset --hard`, so that the subsequent `git checkout` *does* (usually) move, will change the retained information back to the name.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @torek, I had absolutely noticed what you mentioned about old versions of git only having the hash, nothing else.  And new versions mentioning "detached from", but overall it seems like this is basically a bug?  Where I came *from* shouldn't matter, only where I'm going *to*, no? I'd understand this situation if it were the "detached from" state, but when it's "detached at", once it can go to that branch, it shouldn't need any more info.

Comment: The (main?) idea of going from "detached at foo" to "detached from foo" is that if you *add new commits* you're no longer *at* the original hash, you've grown a new, anonymous branch. If you switch away from it, this branch will be abandoned unless you give it a name, so it's nice to point out that you are now in this somewhat dangerous condition.

Comment: That said, yes, if you switch from "hash" to "name" without moving, it might be nice to replace a raw hash with a name. There may be many names for one commit though. The one that should be recorded would be the one you gave to `git checkout`: if you `git checkout origin/master` and then `git checkout v2.3` and they're the same commit, it's probably nice to record "tag: v2.3" now. Whether to call this a *bug* is up to the Git folks.

Comment: I don't necessarily have to concern myself with any of those issues, given this is *purely* for CI builds, so we're never going to be in the situation of commiting new builds, I just wanted a nice, dynamic (from the checked out repo) way to get the detail of exactly what's being built.

Comment: That's a different scenario, though. I'm talking about *the same* command, `git checkout origin/master`, IMO, calling `git branch` should give the same output (about the state of the HEAD) every time, after the checkout command.  *What* to show is up to the git folks, but it should be consistent, I think.